# How to create unique id for users during extract from oracle xml

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g, xml-parsing

I have xmldata in my oracle DB, there are different applicants for a particular appID in my oracle DB. Note the appID is a field in the oracle table while the applicants are in the xmldata(I have multiple applicants in this xml) I would like to create a unique id for the applicants.
In the sample data, there are 3 applicants. how do I create unique ids in my select statement.

```
WITH t( xml ) AS
    (
    SELECT XMLType('<loanApplication xmlns="http://www.abcdef.com/Schema/FCX/1" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <applicantGroup>
         <applicantGroupTypeDd>0</applicantGroupTypeDd>
        <applicant>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>neweg</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>1</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>1500.0</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>RayM</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>6</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>60000</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>TDC</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>8</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>100</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>2007 Hyundai</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>4</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>2500</assetValue>
          </asset>
       </applicant>
      </applicantGroup>
      <applicantGroup>
        <applicantGroupTypeDd>1</applicantGroupTypeDd>
        <applicant>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>neweg</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>2</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>15000.0</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>Bay</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>6</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>60000</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>TDC</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>9</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>100</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>2007 car</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>3</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>2500</assetValue>
          </asset>
       </applicant>
      </applicantGroup>
      <applicantGroup>
        <applicantGroupTypeDd>3</applicantGroupTypeDd>
        <applicant>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>neweg</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>6</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>100.0</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>RayM</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>8</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>60000</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>TDC</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>7</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>100</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>2007 Hyundai</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>5</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>2500</assetValue>
          </asset>
       </applicant>
      </applicantGroup>
        </loanApplication>')
     FROM dual
    )
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT (        
            KEY 'Assets' value y.Assets
            ) assets
    FROM t,
    XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.abcdef.com/Schema/FCX/1'), '/loanApplication/applicantGroup/applicant/asset'
          PASSING xml
          COLUMNS
                Assets INT PATH 'assetValue') y
```

Results, I need

| AppId | applicantId | assetTypeDd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | [1,6,8,4] |
| 1 | 2 | [1,2,6,9,3] |
| 1 | 3 | [3,6,8,7,5] |

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider XPath's `ancestor` axis and count pf `preceding-sibling` since it appears one applicant node falls under each applicantGroup:

```sql
WITH t( xml_data ) AS
    (
    SELECT XMLType('<loanApplication xmlns="http://www.abcdef.com/Schema/FCX/1" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <applicantGroup>
         <applicantGroupTypeDd>0</applicantGroupTypeDd>
        <applicant>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>neweg</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>1</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>1500.0</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>RayM</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>6</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>60000</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>TDC</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>8</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>100</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>2007 Hyundai</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>4</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>2500</assetValue>
          </asset>
       </applicant>
      </applicantGroup>
      <applicantGroup>
        <applicantGroupTypeDd>1</applicantGroupTypeDd>
        <applicant>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>neweg</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>2</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>15000.0</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>Bay</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>6</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>60000</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>TDC</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>9</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>100</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>2007 car</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>3</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>2500</assetValue>
          </asset>
       </applicant>
      </applicantGroup>
      <applicantGroup>
        <applicantGroupTypeDd>3</applicantGroupTypeDd>
        <applicant>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>neweg</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>6</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>100.0</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>RayM</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>8</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>60000</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>TDC</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>7</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>100</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>2007 Hyundai</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>5</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>2500</assetValue>
          </asset>
       </applicant>
      </applicantGroup>
        </loanApplication>')
     FROM dual
    )

SELECT y.ApplicantId AS "applicantId",   
       LISTAGG(y.AssetTypeDd, ',') AS "assetTypeDd",
       LISTAGG(y.Assets, ',') AS "assets"
FROM t,
     XMLTABLE(
          XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.abcdef.com/Schema/FCX/1' AS "d",
                        DEFAULT 'http://www.abcdef.com/Schema/FCX/1'),
          '//d:asset'
          PASSING xml_data
          COLUMNS
                ApplicantId INT PATH 'count(ancestor::applicantGroup/preceding-sibling::*)+1',
                AssetTypeDd INT PATH 'assetTypeDd',
                Assets INT PATH 'assetValue'
    ) y
GROUP BY y.ApplicantId
ORDER BY y.ApplicantId
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e1d372d175d4ed5e8e8390f269c32e21)</kbd>

Comment: I am getting ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression error message when I add appId in the select statement. The appId is not in the xml but it is a field in the table. `SELECT 
 appId AS applicationID
 ,y.ApplicantId AS ApplicantId
 ,LISTAGG(y.AssetTypeDd, ',') AS assetType
 ,LISTAGG(y.Assets, ',') AS asset
 FROM t`

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, I am looking into this now. quick question, how do I dynamically change the xpath supposing I have another node inside the applicant node, for example after asset I have this tag ` <liability> <broker> <cbScraped>Y</cbScraped> <creditLimit>2000</creditLimit> <liabilityAmount>1809</liabilityAmount> <liabilityMonthlyPayment>54</liabilityMonthlyPayment> <liabilityTypeDd>2</liabilityTypeDd> </broker> </liability> ` How do I switch to /liability/broker/liabilityAmount in the same xmltable? Thanks

Comment: Simply add `appId` to `GROUP BY` clause since this is an aggregate query. Re additional XML section, without clear relationship to `asset` (i.e., child/parent), you may have to add another XMLTABLE cross join to parse that other section. But that is a different question to original if we can confirm this solution answered posted question.

Comment: Thank, the solution works when the data is in xml only.